# Tabela sem cor IE

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Estou com um problema na pagina do IE11 porque aparece-me o rectangulo a Branco e no Chrome aparece correctamente. 
[image: Primeira imagem IE11 segunda Google Chrome]

```
<form method="post" action="Procurarquery.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

CSS:

```
.Tabela {
background: #7db9e8; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7db9e8 1%, #1e5799 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-  stop(1%,#7db9e8),color-stop(100%,#1e5799)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7db9e8 1%,#1e5799 100%); /*   Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7db9e8 1%,#1e5799 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7db9e8 1%,#1e5799 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7db9e8 1%,#1e5799 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7db9e8',   endColorstr='#1e5799',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
 }
```

Comment: Eu experimentei no http://jsfiddle.net/ e deu bem

Comment: Pois ai funciona. Mas no IE fica assim a branco

Comment: Você não inseriu o código todo, pelo que vi o background é um gradiente e não uma cor sólida. Insira o CSS que aplica o gradiente, o problema pode ser isso.

Comment: Exactamente, o @Filipe tem razão. Pelo que tens ai (cor sólida e não um gradiente) funciona bem em todo o lado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no CSS, o que você postou está incompleto.
Repare que o que você postou aplica uma cor sólida e não um gradiente como na imagem.

```
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#4682B4;" bgcolor="#4682B4" ...
background-color:#4682B4;
bgcolor="#4682B4"
```

Verifique se o seu CSS é compatível com o IE, veja um exemplo cross browser:

```
background: #7db9e8; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7db9e8 1%, #1e5799 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#7db9e8),color-stop(100%,#1e5799)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7db9e8 1%,#1e5799 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7db9e8 1%,#1e5799 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7db9e8 1%,#1e5799 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7db9e8 1%,#1e5799 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7db9e8', endColorstr='#1e5799',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Veja aqui em funcionamento o código acima: [jsfiddle.net/wLV65/](http://jsfiddle.net/wLV65/)

Tenha atenção que o height 100% herda a altura do pai, ou seja, se o pai não tem uma altura definida, o filho também não terá e isso é suficiente para o gradiente não ser aplicado no IE.
Experimente trocar o height 100% por uma altura fixa, irá passar a funcionar no IE.

Comment: Acrescentei o CSS que me colocou e o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: @user3253195 coloque o seu código aqui http://fiddle.jshell.net/, todo o seu css e o seu html, o problema deve ser outro.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/vA9bk/ 
Mas aqui o codigo funciona sem problemas

Comment: @user3253195 funciona lá sem problemas no IE também? No IE9,10,11?

Comment: So funciona no  fiddle.jshell.net no IE11 Não está a funcionar.

Comment: @user3253195 o problema agora está no seu html. Experimente retirar o width:100% e height:100% da tag style da table e altere a classe .tabela, inserindo uma altura e largura fixa, por exemplo width:500px e height:500px . Repare que passou a funcionar no IE.